# C# cannot connect to vmware

Tags: c#, vmware

I have a project where i will have to build dual stacked virtual machines.  I usually work with powershell but it does not appear to be able to do that.  I may have to use C#.  I am kinda rusty on this but for some reason this code give me an error "Cannot create an instance of the abstract class or interface 'VMware.Vim.VimClient'".

```
using System.Text;
using VMware.Vim;

namespace Vimfunctions
{  

    public class VimFunctions
    {
        protected VimClient ConnectServer(string viServer, string viUser, string viPassword)
        {
            **VimClient vClient = new VimClient();**
            ServiceContent vimServiceContent = new ServiceContent();
            UserSession vimSession = new UserSession();

            vClient.Connect("https://" + viServer.Trim() + "/sdk");
            vimSession = vClient.Login(viUser, viPassword);
            vimServiceContent = vClient.ServiceContent;

            return vClient;
        }
```

I added the reference to the project.  I must have forgot to do something.

Comment: `VimClient` is an abstract class, you need to create an instance of another class that inherits from this one.

Comment: @DavidG, and then add bodies to the function before calling. :-)

Comment: @DavidG: except the fact that all examples on the web actually use `new VimClient();`.

Comment: @ThomasW. I'm going off the error message given, not the VMWare API.

Answer (score 5):

As per https://communities.vmware.com/thread/478700:
"either stick with the PowerCLI 5.5 release as mentioned or to modify your code to use the VimClientImpl class instead of VimClient (which is now an interface)."

A complete simple example I used:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using VMware.Vim;

namespace vSphereCli
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl c = new VimClientImpl();
            ServiceContent sc = c.Connect("https://HOSTNAME/sdk");
            UserSession us = c.Login("admin@vsphere.local", "password");
            IList<VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase> vms = c.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, null, null);
            foreach (VMware.Vim.EntityViewBase tmp in vms)
            {
                VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine vm = (VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine)tmp;
                Console.WriteLine((bool)(vm.Guest.GuestState.Equals("running") ? true : false));
                Console.WriteLine(vm.Guest.HostName != null ? (string)vm.Guest.HostName : "");
                Console.WriteLine("");
            }
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Add a reference to "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\vSphere PowerCLI\VMware.Vim.dll". Update the hostname, password; and volia!

Comment: For version 6.5 (https://developercenter.vmware.com/web/dp/tool/vsphere_powercli/6.5) the reference file is in "C:\Program Files (x86)\VMware\Infrastructure\PowerCLI\Modules\VMware.VimAutomation.Core\VMware.Vim.dll"